# Has anyone tried to parallelize multiple imputation in 'mice' package?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r-mice

I'm aware of the fact that `Amelia` `R` package provides some support for **parallel** *multiple imputation (MI)*. However, preliminary analysis of my study's data revealed that the data is **not** *multivariate normal*, so, unfortunately, I can't use `Amelia`. Consequently, I've switched to using `mice` `R` package for MI, as this package can perform MI on data that is not multivariate normal.

Since the MI process via `mice` is **very slow** (currently I'm using AWS `m3.large` 2-core instance), I've started wondering whether it's possible to parallelize the procedure to save processing time. Based on my review of `mice` documentation and the corresponding JSS paper, as well as `mice`'s source code, it appears that currently the package doesn't support parallel operations. This is sad, because IMHO the MICE algorithm is *naturally parallel* and, thus, its parallel implementation should be relatively easy and it would result in a significant economy in both time and resources.

**Question:** Has anyone tried to parallelize MI in `mice` package, either externally (via `R` parallel facilities), or internally (by modifying the source code) and what are results, if any? Thank you!

Comment: Try the R `Hmisc` package `aregImpute` function which is faster.  To start out, specify that all effects of continuous variables are linear (which is what `mice` assumes).

Comment: @FrankHarrell: I appreciate your advice, Dr. Harrell! I took a quick look at the suggested function's description in the `Hmisc` documentation. The description seems a little overwhelming to me (probably, due to my limited knowledge of the subject matter), plus I noticed that `mice` now has `fastpmm` method, which, I guess, is equal to the corresponding one in `aregImpute()`. Even if I won't end up using `aregImpute()`, I'm sure that I will use some other functions from your amazing `Hmisc` package. Best wishes, Alex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently, I've tried to parallelize *multiple imputation (MI)* via `mice` package externally, that is, by using `R` multiprocessing facilities, in particular `parallel` package, which comes standard with `R` base distribution. Basically, the solution is to use `mclapply()` function to distribute a pre-calculated share of the total number of needed MI iterations and then combine resulting imputed data into a single object. *Performance-wise*, the results of this approach are beyond my most optimistic expectations: the *processing time* decreased from 1.5 hours to **under 7 minutes**(!). That's only on two cores. I've removed one multilevel factor, but it shouldn't have much effect. Regardless, the result is unbelievable!

Comment: These results sound impressive, but unless you have about 12 cores it is a little [too good to be true](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_computing#Amdahl.27s_law_and_Gustafson.27s_law). There is some overhead associated with parallelization and therefore these kinds of gains are highly likely a result from some other contributing factor. Anyway, I've written a short how-to for doing this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040280/parallel-computation-of-multiple-imputation-by-using-mice-r-package

Comment: @MaxGordon: Thank you for the comment. The *results* that I've shared indeed **are true**. I hope that you're not accusing me in not being truthful, which 1) is not my style; 2) I don't have reasons to lie. Whether that **particular** speedup was a result of only using `mclapply()` or that plus some *unaccounted factors* is unclear to me at this point. Currently, I have more urgent tasks to take care of. Having said that, your references look interesting and I will definitely review them in detail when I will have more time.

Comment: Sorry, of course you are truthful. My point was simply that most people should not expect that kind of speedup if they have the common setup with 4-8 cores. My guess is that there may be some factor that changed between the two, I'm not sure why mclapply would do that by itself.

Comment: @MaxGordon: No problem and thank you! I agree with you on this. FYI, that speedup has occurred on an `m3.large` Amazon EC2 instance, which is only 2-core. By the way, I took a quick look at your interesting blog and nice `gmisc` package. Two functions look currently especially appealing to me: `htmlTable` and `getDescriptionsStatsBy`. I might even try them at some point. Best wishes, Alex.